# Does using more than one step-up ring affect quality?

Tags: image-quality

Hi I'm new to photography / videography and would like to know if using 2 or 3 step-rings would cause any vignetting, flaring, or any sort quality reduction?

My case is I'd like to step-up from 49-72mm but being fussy I like the appearance of the lens using more than the 1 step-up ring. In future I'd like a telephoto lens that using 72 filter thread.

In your opinion should I just use the 1 step up of 49-72mm to be safe? Or could I use more than one, say 49-52, 52-56 then 56-72mm as a set.

Thanks and hope to hear your advice

Comment: What lens has the 49mm you are stepping up from, and what camera are you using?

Comment: The lens would be a Sony 50mm 1.8 oss with the Sony a6300.

Answer (score 3):

Not only might vignetting be an issue, but the greater relief between lens and filter could make dust more apparent (in-focus).

Since a [single-piece adapter can be found for US$8](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00030BE2U), I'd use the "sleeker, thinner" approach.

Comment: But the stacked 49-52 + 52-56 + 56-72 looks way cooler!

Comment: Thanks for your opinion DrMoishe! Yes I've seen the stack and it does look nice but I think I might play it safe with the single step-up